# Date retrieve problem in spring boot with hibernate from mysql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to the spring boot and I am facing one issue when retrieving date from the database. I have stored the date in UTC format but when I try to retrieve the date then it converting date again in UTC format. I want a date as I stored in.

E.g Suppose Europe/Berlin Time is 2018-09-27 09:25:00 and the UTC time is 2018-09-27 07:25:00 Then When I insert the data then it is storing date and time as 2018-09-27 07:25:00 but when I am retrieving it then `Instant` will convert the time once again in the UTC so I am getting date as 2018-09-27T05:25:00Z

```
2018-09-27 12:34:40.525 TRACE LAPTOP-A64OROCI---o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor                           : extracted value ([created_2_0_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2018-09-27T05:25:00Z]
```

Below property, I have added in application.properties

spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS= false
spring.jackson.time-zone= UTC

I have added following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Below is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
// Spring application base class
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { WiseLabApiApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
// Specify global exception handler from base package
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = WiseLabApiApplication.class)
public class WiseLabApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


/**
 * Set the UTC time zone
 */
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}

/**
 * Override configure method for deployment war file
 */
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(WiseLabApiApplication.class);
}

/**
 * Starting point of WiseLab Server
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Environment environment = SpringApplication.run(WiseLabApiApplication.class, args).getEnvironment();
    String serverEnvironment = null;
    String[] activeProfiles = null;
    String serverPort = environment.getProperty("server.port");
    if (!Objects.isNull(environment)) {
        activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
        if (activeProfiles.length != 0) {
            serverEnvironment = activeProfiles[0];
            logger.info(
                    "\n\n*****************Server Configuration************************************************************");
            logger.info("WiseLabAPI server started ");
            logger.info("Environment Mode => " + serverEnvironment.toUpperCase());
            logger.info("Server Port => " + serverPort);
            logger.info(
                    "\n\n*************************************************************************************************");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Below is my AuditingConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport(registration=RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AuditingConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Long> auditorProvider() {
        return new SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl();
    }
}

class SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Long> {

    @Override
    public Optional<Long> getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null ||
                !authentication.isAuthenticated() ||
                authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Optional.ofNullable(userPrincipal.getId());
    }
}
```

Below is my base audit class and I have extended base audit class in my model

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdAt", "updatedAt" }, allowGetters = true)
public abstract class BaseEntity  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6783352876165714983L;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Instant createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Instant updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "deleted", columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean deleted = false;


    public BaseEntity() {
    }

    public Instant getCreatedAt() {
        System.out.println("Date in getCreatedAt : ");
        System.out.println(createdAt);
        return createdAt;
    }


    public Instant getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Instant createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Instant updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

}
```

Below is my master model class in that I have extended BaseEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admin_group_master")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE admin_group_master SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
@Loader(namedQuery = "findAdminGroupMasterById")
@NamedQuery(name = "findAdminGroupMasterById", query = "SELECT grp FROM AdminGroupMaster grp WHERE grp.id = ? AND grp.deleted = false")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
@DynamicUpdate
public class AdminGroupMaster extends BaseEntity {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6667484763475502316L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

Below is the adminGroupMaster repository class

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AdminGroupMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<AdminGroupMaster, Long> {

List<AdminGroupMaster> findByCreateByCustomer(Customer customer);
}
```

Below is my service class

```
@Service
public class AdminGroupService {

    public BaseResponse<GroupListResponse> getAdminGroupDetails(UserPrincipal currentAdmin) throws CustomException {

    // Get all admin groups based on customer id
        List<AdminGroupMaster> adminGroupDetails = adminGroupMasterRepository
                .findByCreateByCustomer(currentAdmin.getCustomer());

                adminGroupDetails.stream().forEach((groupDetails) -> {
                    System.out.println("Created Date Time : ");
                    System.out.println( groupDetails.getCreatedAt());
                });
    }
}
```

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I have stored the date in UTC"_: that doesn't exist. Date are stored as date. You can then format it to be displayed for a given timezone, which is only a different representation of the same instant. And it is what does jackson: using the UTC representation of the stored date to convert it to json.

Comment: Yes true I want to do that only but when I retrieve I am getting a different date. As I mentioned in the example I have stored as 2018-09-27 07:25:00 and when I try to get the date then I am getting 2018-09-27 05:25:00

Comment: because '2018-09-27 07:25:00' refers to the default timezone (opposed to 2018-09-27T07:25:00Z) of your system and I bet you are at GMT+2 (France/Switzerland/Germany?). That is 05:25 at GMT+0. The problem occurs because your first date (when you save it) is either on a different timezone you didn't specify, or because the display should specify a different timezone

Comment: Yes, I am in Germany. I have set the default time zone as UTC as @PostConstruct
void init() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}

Comment: what you should get is that the date at save time (d1) is equals to the date you just got at load time (d2): ``d1.equals(d2)==true``. There is no bug. Only different ways to display the same instant in the universe timeline.

Comment: This is not the same date which I stored. When I try to retrieve the date then I am getting 2018-09-27T05:25:00Z and When I try to convert back into europe/berlin time then it will give me 2018-09-27 07:25:00 again. but the actual europe/berlin time was 2018-09-27 09:25:00 when I inserted data. So the europe/berlin time was 2018-09-27 09:25:00 and As per UTC it stores 2018-09-27 07:25:00 that is correct but When I retrieve it gives me 2018-09-27T05:25:00Z. From this time how can I get the 2018-09-27 09:25:00 time?

Comment: ok, try to move the ``TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`` as the first instruction of your main method. I suspect it to happen a bit to late, between the creation of the created_date and the save of your entity (this is weird to apply such a global configuration in an interceptor rather than the soonest possible in the application lifecycle).

Comment: I have just commented the the TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); but it is still not wroking. it is still giving me 2018-09-27T05:25:00Z

Answer (score 0):

**--- Make sure the timezone of db is UTC**

1. Check you application.properties, make sure you add ***useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC*** to your mysql url.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

2. Add the following to application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
```

**--- Make sure the timezone of your server is UTC**

1. The following is needed:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```